# Keeping a line empty if text is shorter, if longer populating that line

Tags: html, css

I have the following `HTML` and `JSON` setup:

**.html**

`<span class="pop-product-name">{{name}}</span>`

**.json**

`"name" : "Enditatem Product Name Optional Line Two",`

My question is, how can I go about limiting the first line to be `Enditatem Product Name` only, while keeping a second line empty (non breaking space style), but if the `name` is longer, the `Optional Line Two` will go on the second line. Is even the `<span>` element an appropriate one to use?

**EDIT**

The project is a webshop template:

[image]

The first line needs to be only `Enditatem Product Name`. If there is no additional text, the second line needs to be a blank non breaking space. IF however, there is a `Optional Line Two`, it should then appear on the second line.

Comment: What about putting a CSS `height` to your `span` ? If you want a line break, it's probably better to use an html block element, maybe a <div> or <p>.

Comment: Are you using twig? If so, you can make a quite simple script to manage that...

Comment: @Magicprog.fr In addtion to `max-width` as well, I think it would fit, but the problem he may experience is if the Optional Line 2 gets to be longer than Enditatem Product Name.

Comment: please provide us demo live if possible if not some images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give width to `<span>`, if for example the `<span>` `width:100px;` try `width:50px;` make it as much **(Enditatem Product Name)** `width`, **(Optional Line Two)** it will automatically comes in the second line once you do that and if it's no second line, the second line will be empty and you might give `height` to your `<span>` just in case if second line is empty, by the way in order to change `width` for `<span>` you have to give (`position: absolute;`) and it might change the place of your `<span>` you might need to `margine` it. try this code:

```css
.pop-product-name {
  width: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="pop-product-name">Enditatem Product Name Optional Line Two</span>
```

because I'm not able to do it as json call and angular too so I did it basic span and should works for you, let me know if you have any question